# In what circumstances would one use the word 'frangible'?

Tags: word-usage

When can / should we use the word frangible?

Please give some examples of its use in a sentence.

ADDED:
I know that it is a very specific word, But I would like to know where this word appears: biology, physics, ...

Comment: [**frangible**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frangible) adjective: *easily broken; breakable*. Example usage from that dictionary definition: *Most **frangible** toys are not suitable for young children.* Please explain what exactly you don't understand about that or alternative dictionary definitions. It's actually [very uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frangible%2Cfriable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrangible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfriable%3B%2Cc0) compared to the closely-related ***friable***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This isn't a question about meaning but about appropriate use.

Comment: I know that it is a very specific word, But I would like to know where this word appears: biology, physics, ...?

Comment: @StoneyB: I agree your own answer that there are precious few "valid" contexts apart from *frangible ammo/bullets/stone*. And to be honest I wouldn't have used that dictionary example myself, 'cos I tend to think of it as implying ***intended** to be broken [into small pieces]*, or ***suitable** for being [deliberately] broken*. So regardless of whether it's strictly "correct" or not, I'm okay with [*frangible soil*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22frangible+soil%22) which would more often be ***friable***.

Comment: I am going to appeal on Meta and in Chat for this question to be reopened.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frangible

Comment: @User1 - That's interesting, but it doesn't answer the O.P.'s question. The entry says: "Common biscuits or crackers are examples of frangible materials, while fresh bread .. is not frangible." That may be so, but I would **never** tell my waitress: "Can I get some different crackers for my soup? These are not frangible enough." (Incidentally, there's been a bit of debate going on about this question. If you left the link just to be helpful, then thanks for being helpful. However, if you left the link thinking that it would prove this is general reference, then I'd ask folks to reconsider.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Frangible* is a very fancy replacement for "breakable". Regardless of the examples you find in dictionaries, the word is virtually unused outside of very technical contexts such as engineering and product specifications. The first hundred hits returned on a Google search on the word yielded:

19 dictionary definitions
26 uses in technical specifications or rules involving "breakaway" safety devices
 2 uses as screen names
 2 uses for names of videogame entitites

All the rest were references to "frangible ammunition", bullets designed to break apart rather than deforming or ricocheting.

Unless you are an engineer or an avid gun-user, I think you can dismiss this word from your own use. In most ordinary contexts "breakable" will be a more natural term.

Comment: And the OP couldn't do a Google search or look in Wikipedia? These are as basic as dictionaries.

Comment: ^The close rationale in a nutshell.

Comment: @User1, Nihilist The OP's problem is not about meaning it's about usage. When is it appropriate to use? That information is not given in a dictionary.

Comment: +1 I think that some commenters and answerers on ELU who like to show off their vocab use it a bit! (maybe where this question came from?)

Comment: @Araucaria - I suppose it's possible, but the word _frangible_ only appears [once](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=frangible) on ELU.

Comment: @J.R. Ah, but there's the [comments too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211194/a-word-for-a-skill-that-if-lost-may-never-be-able-to-be-reacquired#comment449386_211194) and  [here as well for example!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260873/igible-suffix#comment572498_260873)

Comment: @Araucaria - Ah, I forgot about the comments. Nice catch.